# How to upload Image to database using Php

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, upload

I have written image upload files and it show error "Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\Schmgt\svr\upload_image.php on line 3"

But i am unable to find any issue in my code. Please help me.

HTML form

```
<form action="../svr/upload_image.php" method="post"  id="form_po" enctype="multipar/form-data">
                                <div class="row"><br/></div>
                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-md-2"> </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <?php 
                                        $nic=$_GET['nic'];
                                        ?>
                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="txt_po_number" name="txt_nic" value="<?php echo $nic; ?>" readonly>                                       
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <br/>

                        <br/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div style="border: 1px solid black">
                                    <img src="../img/user.png" width="235px" height="250px">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div style="border: 1px solid black">
                                    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <br/>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-10">




                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-right: 50px;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <input type="submit" id="btn-next" name="btn-submit" class="form-control btn-success" value="Finish">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br/>

                        </form>
```

PHP file upload-image.php file

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$target="../img/".  basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

$img=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$text=$_POST['txt_nic'];

var_dump($img);die;

$query1="INSERT INTO image(nic,image)VALUES('$text','$img')";

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){

}  else {

}

?>
```

Comment: this is a typo question, it's just missing a `t` in this `enctype="multipar/form-data"`

Comment: you forgot to run `$query1`

Comment: The question is still a typo.

Comment: Thank you So much that is a issue

Answer (score 1):

check your enctype in form. it should be like enctype="multipart/form-data" and you also forgot to run query.

Comment: you should just vote as a typo - that's all this is

Comment: Your edit about forgetting to run the query; you should have [credited Rishi about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604921/how-to-upload-image-to-database-using-php#comment76196939_44604921). The question is still a typo.

Comment: Thank you So much that is a issue